# Keras output layer step treshold

Tags: keras, neural-network, sequential

I am trying to build a Keras model.

```
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
  tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),  
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(50, activation='sigmoid'),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(50, activation='linear'),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(100, activation='sigmoid'),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(25, activation='softmax'),
  tf.keras.layers.ReLU(max_value=1)
])
```

Although the desired output should be 1 or 0. I understand we can't do that due to stochastic gradient descent. But is there any step layer that I can set a treshold so I get 0 or 1 as the output? The desired output has a shape of (1,25)

Answer (score 0):

For a binary output you should use the `sigmoid` activation at the output, and the `binary_crossentropy` loss. Then you can simply round or apply a threshold of 0.5 to the output to get binary 0/1 values.